# How to disable WYSIWYG Editor v1.1.1 Context menu

Tags: ckeditor

How to disable WYSIWYG Editor v1.1.1 Context menu
I have tried this but dont works

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
config.removePlugins = 'contextmenu';
//also try this below code
config.removePlugins = 'contextmenu,liststyle,tabletools';
};
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use an module to override the settings

```
function MODULENAME_wysiwyg_editor_settings_alter(&$settings, $context) {
  if ($context['profile']->editor == 'ckeditor') {
    $settings['removePlugins'] = 'scayt,menubutton,contextmenu';
   }
}
```

Do not forget to replace MODULENAME with your own module name.